# Magento 2 Create new "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" Attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I need to create a **special input type** in adminhtml product form. My input will display as a table but save data as a standard text input.

I need to create a **"Catalog Input Type for Store Owner"**. With input renderer is text

File: Magento/Customattribute/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Customattribute" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

File: Magento/Customattribute/etc/config.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <general>
            <validator_data>
                <input_types>
                    <customattributetype>customattributetype</customattributetype>
                </input_types>
            </validator_data>
        </general>
    </default>
</config>
```

File: Magento/Customattribute/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_product_attribute_types">
        <observer name="custom_attributes_type" instance="Magento\Customattribute\Observer\AddAttributeTypeObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

File: Magento/Customattribute/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute" type="Magento\Customattribute\Model\Catalog\ResourceModel\Attribute" />
</config>
```

File: Magento/Customattribute/Model/Catalog/ResourceModel/Attribute.php

```
<?php


namespace Magento\Customattribute\Model\Catalog\ResourceModel;

class Attribute extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute
{
    protected function _beforeSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {
        if ($object->getFrontendInput() === 'customattributetype') {
            $object->setBackendType('varchar');
            $object->setData('frontend_input_renderer', 'Magento\Customattribute\Block\Attribute\Renderer');
        }
        return parent::_beforeSave($object);
    }
}
```

File: Magento/Customattribute/etc/config.xml

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Customattribute\Block\Attribute;

class Renderer extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Text
{

    public function getHtml()
    {
        $this->addClass('customattributetype-input');
        return parent::getHtml();
    }
}
```

File: Magento/Customattribute/Observer/AddAttributeTypeObserver.php

```
<?php


namespace Magento\Customattribute\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddAttributeTypeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getResponse();
        $types = $response->getTypes();
        $types[] = [
            'value' => 'customattributetype',
            'label' => __('customattributetype'),
        ];
        $response->setTypes($types);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

File: Magento/Customattribute/registration.php

```
<?php


\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magento_Customattribute',
    __DIR__
);
```

============================================================

1. It has created successfully  a "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner"
2. I go to Stores -> Product-> Add New Attribute with "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" = "customattributetype".
   Click Save Attribute
3. Add the new attribute to the Default attribute set
4. Product -> Catalog -> Add Product (simple product)

It has an error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/magento2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 223 and defined in /var/www/html/magento2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:174 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(223): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('percent', NULL) #1 /var/www/html/magento2.3.0/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(85): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('percent', 'percent', Array) #2 /var/www/html/magento2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(164): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare() #3 /var/www/html/magento2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(161): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiCompo in /var/www/html/magento2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 174"

**Please help me**

Comment: Same Issue. Any Solution to fix this?

Comment: @Pavithra take a look at my answer below if you still got this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing after you, and here is my solution:

The reason which cause this issue is you set the `'value' => 'customattributetype',` it is not default values.

This value should be "text, price, select, media, multiselect .."
[image]

You can check the default values in `eav_attribute` table after you create a new attribute.
[image]

So the solution is you change the `'value' => 'customattributetype',` to `'value' => 'text',` or something in the default values, then delete/remove the old attribute and create a new one.

And don't forget to put the old attribute out of the attribute set.